# Raise an event on intent activity open

Tags: android, events, android-intent

is it possible to generate an on click event of another activity with an intent of other class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
//what ever it is in classA

}
```

with this type in another class

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ClassA.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

or just assume like that generate an event when we go to another class through intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want to run some code from `onClick()`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    someMethod();
}
```

you can always trigger it with a parameter sent via the `Intent`

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ClassA.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("some_flag", true);
context.startActivity(i);
```

and then in `ClassA`'s `onCreate()`

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("some_flag")) {
    someMethod();
}
```